# Property/method not found?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, properties

I'm trying to call a method from the Document class, as well as a method of an object that Document has a pointer to. I suspect I'm making some basic mistake; here's are the relevant portions of what I wrote:

Document.h:

```
@interface Document : NSDocument
<NSTableViewDataSource>

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTableView *listTable;
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *items;
```

MyTableviewDataSource.m:

```
- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView setObjectValue:(id)anObject
  forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn
          row:(NSInteger)rowIndex;
{
[Document.items replaceObjectAtIndex:rowIndex withObject:anObject];

}
```

Xcode highlights that last message send in MyTableViewDataSource and gives the error:

```
Property 'items' not found on object of type 'Document'
```

Sorry if this question is confusing, I am new to coding and am struggling to articulate the stuff I've learned in words. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The property has not been synthesized in your Document.m file - or autosynthesized in the header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line:

```
[Document.items replaceObjectAtIndex:rowIndex withObject:anObject];
```

is trying to call `items` on the *class* `Document` - you need an *instance* of `Document`. Somewhere you must create a `Document` instance and that is what your method needs to reference.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I knew it was something silly like that.